# Is there a Homebrew command to downgrade from HEAD to stable version of a package?

Tags: homebrew

I `brew install --HEAD`'d `node` recently to see if the upstream version fixed a bug I was experiencing. (It did!)

Now I'd like to downgrade back to the stable, bottled version. Is there a simple command to do so?

`brew reinstall` simply pulls & rebuilds the `HEAD` version from upstream. (Where does Homebrew "remember" my HEAD preference?)

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies && brew install` is of course possible, but annoying given that it would also delete my build history & install receipts, which I'd like to keep around a bit if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope! Question is still out here, awaiting one.

Comment: Should rather be in Apple stackexchange

Comment: @mTvare I don’t necessarily think so, Homebrew has variants which share the same commands for a variety of OSes now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the same thing for pyenv while waiting for version 2.1.0 to make it into homebrew-core. I figured I'd simply uninstall pyenv and reinstall it without `--HEAD`, but when I attempted to do so, Homebrew told me:

```
Only uninstalling HEAD version because multiple versions are installed
```

(Or something like that.)

The documentation doesn't really explain this, as far as I can tell, but I did find an explanation [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/32295):

> uninstall first removes whichever version is "active", i.e. linked into the main prefix. What happens when you run uninstall again depends on how many other versions are installed: if there is only one, it is removed, otherwise it errors out because it doesn't know which one to uninstall (unless you pass --force).

So I didn't need to do anything else, aside from delete the pyenv repository that Homebrew cloned under ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/pyenv--git. (I think the fact that it doesn't remove this might be a bug.)

Now, if you first uninstalled node stable, then installed HEAD, your situation might be different.

(I know this might not be a great *answer*, but it's too long for a comment.)

Comment: Indeed, helpful! So if you plan ahead by installing stable, _then_ HEAD, you should be able to uninstall just HEAD and relink stable?

Comment: @JacobFord I believe so, although I didn't need to relink anything.